# Creating a DMZ with two routers

Tags: networking, router, firewall, subnet, dmz

Hopefully it's okay to post semi-"I am learning" questions on this forum! Basically, I have two routers (both Netgear D834G's) and would like to setup a DMZ at home (merely for learning purposes and fun!). I'm here for some advice on where to start!

I assume I will have both routers daisy chained - the ADSL line connected to the first router, then a patch cable from Port 1 to my 2nd router. All my 'DMZ' servers (Web Server for example) would sit connected to the first router, and my 'Safe' home PC's connected to the 2nd router further down the chain.

The question is how I setup the 2nd router in terms of it IP configuration etc. (the router is my DHCP source), or is this even possible? Maybe I'm thinking about this the totally wrong way! For example, would the WAN IP be the IP of the first router etc.

Many thanks,

T.C

(This is a post I made from ServerFault, I have re-posted on advice to post here, mainly because I'm keen for a response :) )

Comment: DO NOT CROSSPOST. If it should be on a different site, we'll move it.

Comment: You must have missed this back on SF, where I said : "Once a few more people vote the same way, it will be moved automatically - no need for you to re-post the question"

Answer (score 1):

Setup the first router as a normal router (without NAT). You'll need to get multiple IPs and likely have to pay more for them (contact your ISP). The Second router would be configured as a NAT router. NAT isn't actually necessary at all, it just saves you from getting a bunch more IPs from your ISP; and coincidentally breaks a bunch of stuff like end-to-end routing (some people consider this to be "safer" but it's nothing a properly configured firewall can't do).